What is unique about Asaf, the author of some Tehillim?
Particularly now in 5784 with the war in Eretz Yisrael and rising open antisemitism across the world, many Rabbonim (e.g. the Agudah, OU, etc.) are suggesting we say Tehillim 79, 80, and 83 among others. Although Asaf did not write many perakim, those three are particularly among the ones he authored - what is unique about Asaf that he merited to have his Tehillim said during particularly difficult times in exile?

Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/118946/13811

Not sure what is the reason for the bava-batra tag

Asaf is on Bava-Batra 14b
